# Print unicode character with code bigger than four hex digits

Tags: java, unicode, printing

I am trying to print emoticons on screen using unicode text for emoticons.

From a [list of Emoticons from Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons), I found that these are of the form
U+1F6xx__ ie. 5 characters hexadecimal.

How am I supposed to print a smiley with text code as:
`U+1F60A`

Please help.

Comment: You need to use a font with that Unicode character set.

Comment: These are unicode 6.1 texts, so are these supported. If using these is not possible, an alternate method if provide will help.

Comment: How so? I am just writing a simple System,out.print statement for that.

Comment: If you are using `System.out.print` you will have to make sure the console you are printing to supports unicode, most won't by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Java do:

```
System.out.println("\uD83D\uDE40");
```

You can use this [tool for conversion](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/), as the emoticons listed on that wikipedia page are the actual fonts you can just copy 'n' paste them into the text box labelled "characters" and click convert

Comment: @vish4071 glad it helped.  By the way, if someone correctly answers your question you can accept it by clicking the tick mark next to the question 

Comment: thanks, and thanks for the opportunity to legitimately pepper StackO with emoticons 

Answer (score 12):

Try the next with some font with support for this characters:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int codePoint = 0x1F600; codePoint <= 0x1F64F;) {
        System.out.print(Character.toChars(codePoint));
        codePoint++;
        if (codePoint % 16 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

Answer (score 0):

This helps you to print the entire screen with smiley faces:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {      
       for(int j=0; j<80;j++)
       {
           System.out.print("\u263A");
       }
    System.out.println();}
    }
}
```

Outer loop is for jumping to new line inner loop is to print the smiley faces.

Output:

```
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺☺
```